# Numpy ValueError broadcasting list of tuples into an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm observing some odd behaviour using numpy broadcasting. The problem is illustrated below, where running the first piece of code produces an error:

```
A = np.ones((10))
B = np.ones((10, 4))
C = np.ones((10))
np.asarray([A, B, C])

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,4) into shape (10)
```

If I instead expand the dimensions of B, using `B = np.expand_dims(B, axis=0)`, it will successfully create the array, but it now has (not surprisingly) the wrong dimensions:

```
array([array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]),
   array([[[1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.]]]),
   array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])], dtype=float32)
```

Why does it fail to broadcast the first example, and how can I end up with an array like below (notice only double brackets around the second array)? Any feedback is much appreciated.

```
array([array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]),
   array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.]]),
   array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: `np.hstack([A[:,None], B, C[:,None]])`?

Comment: This doesn't quite work as it creates (in the example above) a new array of shape `(10,6)` and not `(3,)`or `(1,3)` as I need.

Comment: So, you need an object array with a shape of (3,)?

Comment: Yep, or to be precise, once I join (or append) 5 of these together I need them to be of shape (5, 3)

Comment: The common first dimensions (10) in all the arrays sends `np.array` down a faulty path, trying to create a size (10,?) array.  Keep in mind the default behavior for `np.array` is to create a multidimensional (numeric) array.  Creating an object array is a fall back option. With this error yet another possibility.

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj, that makes sense! Also explains why the answer below works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including, say, `None` prevents the broadcasting, so this workaround is an option:

```
np.asarray([A, B, C, None])[:-1]
```

Here the outcome:

```
array([array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]),
       array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]),
       array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])], dtype=object)
```